# Should I escape the attributes when using get_month_link?

Tags: date-time

I am not sure should I use `esc_attr()` with `get_month_link()` like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_attr( get_month_link( get_the_time('Y'), get_the_time('m') ) ); ?>">
<?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' )  ); ?></a>
```

Or should I code it like this (without escaping):

```
<a href="<?php echo get_month_link( get_the_time('Y'), get_the_time('m') ) ; ?>">
<?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' )  ); ?></a>
```

So security wise which is the best option? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, escaping everything (and as close to output as possible) is a way to go. Right until the point excessive escaping is causing issues in specific circumstances.

Note that while this happens in context of attribute, `esc_url()` is more fitting for URLs.

> Always use esc_url when sanitizing URLs (in text nodes, attribute nodes or anywhere else).
>
> [Codex > Data Validation > URLs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#URLs)